# Remove null bytes from the beginning of a stream

Tags: c#, stream, null

I have a class in a dll which parses a file and returns a Stream which represents an FAT image (or any **other**)

My problem is when there is any **other** image the class creates about 3702 (on average) null bytes at the beginning of the stream.

So I have to edit the stream first and then save it to a file.

I have a code already but it works slow.

[Note : *fts* is the returned FileStream.]

```
BufferedStream bfs = new BufferedStream(fts);
BinaryReader bbr = new BinaryReader(bfs);
byte[] all_bytes = bbr.ReadBytes((int)fts.Length);

List<byte> nls = new List<byte>();
int index = 0;

foreach (byte bbrs in all_bytes)
{
    if (bbrs == 0x00)
    {
        index++;
        nls.Add(bbrs);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

byte[] nulls = new byte[nls.Count];
nulls = nls.ToArray();

//File.WriteAllBytes(outputDir + "Nulls.bin", nulls);
long siz = fts.Length - index;
byte[] file = new byte[siz];

bbr.BaseStream.Position = index;
file = bbr.ReadBytes((int)siz);

bbr.Close();
bfs.Close();
fts.Close();

bfs = null;
fts = null;

fts = new FileStream(outputDir + "Image.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
bfs = new BufferedStream(fts);

bfs.Write(file, 0, (int)siz);

bfs.Close();
fts.Close();
```

Now, my question is :

How can I remove the nulls more efficiently and faster than the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pushing bytes onto a List you could simply loop through your stream until you find the first non-null byte and then just copy the array from there using Array.Copy.

I would think about something like this (untested code):

```
int index = 0;
int currByte = 0;

while ((currByte = bbrs.ReadByte()) == 0x00)
{
    index++;
}

// now currByte and everything to the end of the stream are the bytes you want.
```

Comment: why should i use the currByte? I dont notice any difference.
and definitely some time is saved....

Comment: @WritZ: You want to save the currByte because when the while loop exits it will contain the first byte you need to save. Otherwise you will lose that first byte (unless you instead move the stream back by one byte). Looking again at BinaryReader, you could also use PeekChar so that the stream isn't advanced in your while condition (but remember to advance it in the body of the loop!)

Comment: No need! Image Size = _fts.Length - index_. AllBytes is whole Stream then Use the Array.Copy to Copy the bytes after index.I have already done this...

Comment: @Writz: Fair enough. In my mind I wouldn't have read all the bytes into an array first, but it's a fairly minor optimization.